# Не работает конфигурация с помощью макросов

Tags: c++, макросы

Я делаю свою библиотеку и решил сделать конфигурацию с помощью макросов для неё. Вкратце о проблеме: Есть 2 класса. BRange и BIndex. Они будут использоваться параметром в будущих классах (для индексации). Так же я захотел возможность задавать индекс начиная с 1. То есть: 1 2 3 4 5, а не 0 1 2 3 4. Для этого я сделал 2 макроса которые бы взяли в себя 1 параметр(имя переменной) и приводили бы его в обычный индекс. То есть если была включена индексация с 1, то я просто бы отнимал единицу у числа и получал индекс. Проблема в этом: Почему-то даже после включения этой индексации макрос всегда становится таким же, как и в выключенном состоянии. Я уже просто не знаю что с этим делать. Изначально я пытался избавиться от того, чтобы у макроса который включает индексацию было какое-то значение. После я копировал имена макросов так-как мог ошибиться. Вставлял это в файл BIndex.h / BRange.h. (Изначально я использовал для этого другой файл - BConst.h). Кучу раз смотрел на отсутствие логических ошибок. Ничего не помогает. Скинул скрины и ссылку на архив с проектом.

[image: На скрине видно как я объявляю макрос]

[image: Тут видно как объявляется макрос для индексации]

[image: Но макрос почему-то все равно false]

[image: И этот так-же]

И если что - это не баг IDE. При компиляции результаты так же неверные:

[image: файл main]

[image: Вывод в консоль]

**Ссылка на файлы проекта: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mPZuVgL4hEhMc0_xSGsgIqvB_KJboq9I/view?usp=sharing**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Задавать макросы флажками компилятора.
2. Сделать файл а-ля `blib_config.h`. Туда свалить дефолтные значения макросов (как вариант - закоменченные), и предлагать пользователю менять их, если он хочет.

   Минус - ручное изменение хедера как-то не особо ложится на всякие пакетные менеджеры и т.п.
3. ```cpp
   #if __has_include("blib_config.h")
   #include "blib_config.h"
   #endif
   ```

   Или, что примерно то же самое: имя файла засунуть в макрос (вместе с кавычками, иначе не проканает), и условием сделать `#ifdef`, а не `__has_include` - тогда не нужен C++20.

   Тогда по дефолту конфига не будет, и юзер сможет его создать если захочет.

Последний вариант мне нравится больше всего.

Но сама идея - не нравится. Это все баловство. Заставляйте юзеров использовать единственно правильную систему индексации (надеюсь с 0, но это вы решаете).

Представьте: вашу библиотеку использует еще одна библиотека, а потом обе эти библиотеки использует какое-то приложение. Как будете справляться с разными настроками в производной библиотеке и приложении? Предлагать авторам производных библиотек везде втыкать этот макрос конвертации индексов? Фу. Гарантированно кто-нибдуь его забудет, а возможно вы сами.

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите, когда вы компилируете `main.cpp`, у вас макрозначение `BLIB_BINDEX_ADVANCED_INDEXING` определено.

А когда вы компилируете `bindex.cpp`, например - то как по-вашему, оно определено или нет?... А у вас ведь этот код прилинковывается и вызывается из `main.cpp`...

Понимаете, в чем дело? В `main.cpp` нет никакой разницы, определено `BLIB_BINDEX_ADVANCED_INDEXING` или нет! Потому что оно играет роль в `getindex()`, которая вызывается из *скомпилированного отдельно* файла `bindex.cpp`, которому плевать, что вы там написали в `main.cpp`...

Comment: Так. Теперь я понял. Но теперь не понятно как мне реализовать то что я хочу. Конечно можно просто засунуть всё из cpp файла в h файл, но разве нельзя обойтись без этого? Например в том же boost вроде есть такая-же конфигурация, и там всё  прекрасно работает.

Comment: Лучше всего забыть о макросах в С++. Но если вы таки очень хотите с макросами - то вынесите настройки в отдельный `setup.h`, каковой включайте во все файлы проекта и, соответственно, *перекомпилируйте всё при изменении конфигурации*. не пытайтесь сделать библиотечный файл через макросы: тогда это будет библиотека с одной версией кода (кода для другого варианта настроек в ней просто не будет). Тогда надо использовать не макросы, а, например, переменные, синглтоны или что еще... Но выбор кода должен происходить уже при выполнении.